# Make all elements in a DIV act as a link except other links

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, window.location

I have a div, and within that div, various elements (h3, p, span, a, etc.). 
I made the whole div clickable with jquery:

```
$(".play").click(function(){
   window.location=$(this).find("a.play-detail").attr("href"); 
   return false;
});
```

It all works fine. Except that i have 2 other links in the DIV and I can't access them anymore (the DIV-click takes over).
Here's an exemple of the structure:

```
<div class="play">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <a>One link</a> <!-- not working!! -->
  <a class="play-detail">Link for the whole div</a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you wont be able to access the anchor tags click since the divs click will get activared first

Comment: try e.preventDefault() than return false.... which will prevent all child links too.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**:

```
$(".play").click(function(){
    window.location=$(this).find("a.play-detail").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});

$(".play a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qasM5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this?

```
$(".play").click(function(e){
   if(e.target.nodeName != "A"){
     window.location=$(this).find("a.play-detail").attr("href"); 
     return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is the event target, to check for this you first have to grab the event object that jquery provides. You can then check for the target:

```
$(".play").click(function(e){
   if(!$(e.target).is('a')){ //this checks if the clicked element was an a tag
      window.location=$(this).find("a.play-detail").attr("href"); 
      return false;
   }
});
```

Also I have to say it's a little weird to use links like that, but that's up to you.

Comment: But then the DIV isn't sending any more link.

Comment: You can also check for the id or classname of a certain link you want to exclude:

    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('.someclass))

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `event` object to the handler, and then use that to determine whether or not to run the code:

```
$('.play').click(function(event) {

   var $target = $(event.target); // this is the element which was clicked

   if ( $target.is('a') && !$target.hasClass('play-detail') ) {
     return; // don't execute any code beyond this point if the
             // target is an anchor without the 'play-detail' class
   }      

   event.preventDefault();
   window.location = $(this).find('a.play-detail').attr('href'); 


});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx6zX/6/)